# Retrieving FLDAS evapotranspiration data (NASA/FLDAS/NOAH01/C/GL/M/V001) via GEE and converting units to mm/year

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth-engine, javascript, convert

I am using GEE for retrieving FLDAS evapotranspiration data (NASA/FLDAS/NOAH01/C/GL/M/V001) for my study area. In the end, I need a **raster image where each pixel has a value for annual evapotranspiration in mm/year**.

The original data comes in kg m-2 s-1, so I used sum() and multiplied by 86400 (number of seconds in a day) and 30.4375 (average number of days in a month) to get the annual values. The values I get are however not consistent with the literature for my study area which is why I think there might be an error in the code, related to conversion of the units.

```
// set start and end year
var year = 1986; // Change Year>

// make a date object
var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1, 1);

var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year + 1, 1, 1);

//FLDAS
var fldas = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/FLDAS/NOAH01/C/GL/M/V001').select('Evap_tavg');
var annualEvap = fldas.filter(ee.Filter.date(startdate,
enddate)).sum().multiply(86400).multiply(30.4375).clip(StudyArea);

var eViz = {
 min: 0.0,
 max: 1000,
 opacity: 1.0,
 palette: ["black", "blue", "purple", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "red"]
 };

Map.centerObject(StudyArea, 7);
Map.addLayer(annualEvap, eViz, 'AnnualEvapotranspiration_'+year);

// Export AnnualPrecipitation to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
image: annualEvap,
description: 'AnnualEvapotranspiration_'+year,
scale: 11132,
folder: 'AnnualEvapotranspiration',
maxPixels:1.0E13,
region: StudyArea
});
```

[image: Code]

Comment: thank you for your quick answer! However, I should have been more clear with my actual question though. In the end, I do not need a list of values per month, but instead a **raster image where each pixel has a value for annual evapotranspiration in mm/year** for my study area. Sorry for not being clear enough about that!

Comment: There is not difficult to convert "a list of values per month" in a raster image where each pixel has a value for annual evapotranspiration in mm/year. However, it could be convenient an estimated area or your study area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several issues in your code. You should use an **ee.Reducer** for getting evaporation values instead images. First of all, I'm going to review units. Units in kg m-2 s-1 are equivalents to l m-2 s-1 or mm s-1 (because water density is 1). So, multiplied values by 86400 for converting them in daily values is correct. On the other hand, you are using 30.4375 for obtaining monthly values but, you could use exact values for each month (31, 28 or 29, 31, 30 and so on) with a slightly programing effort (however, I'm going to use your conversion factor).

My [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/bb8d8d8cdc9a9b7fe1554d50c3c4e302) looks as follows for an arbitrary **StudyArea** in USA:

```
var StudyArea = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-87.71284585393005, 31.536875310455653],
          [-87.71284585393005, 31.439676530896936],
          [-87.55217080510192, 31.439676530896936],
          [-87.55217080510192, 31.536875310455653]]], null, false);

Map.addLayer(StudyArea);
Map.centerObject(StudyArea);

// set start and end year
var year = 1986; // Change Year>

// make a date object
var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1, 1);

var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year + 1, 1, 1);

//FLDAS
var fldas = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/FLDAS/NOAH01/C/GL/M/V001')
  .select('Evap_tavg')
  .filterDate(startdate,enddate);

print(fldas);

var getEvaporation = function(image) {

    var value_evap = ee.Image(image)
      .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), StudyArea) 
      .get('Evap_tavg');

    return ee.Number(value_evap).multiply(86400).multiply(30.4375);

  };

var evaporation_list = fldas.toList(fldas.size()).map(getEvaporation);

print("monthly values", evaporation_list);

print("annualEvap", evaporation_list.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()));
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, I got result of following picture where it can be observed monthly and yearly values (mm) for referred area (as mean). So, if you want to process several years you need to export them as table instead images.

[image]